# Detect Brown colour object using opencv

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I want find Brown colour Object in Image.I have done following process:

1. Convert image BGR to HSV
2. I have use inRange function of opencv lib to find brown colour.

> cv::inRange(src, Scalar(9, 95, 95),Scalar(17, 255, 255), dest);

3. and  finding contour but i did not get contour.

**Input Image**

[image: Eye with brown iris]

**Question**

I want detect brown colour of eye in above image .When I use above range for brown colour i got zero contour.

is above range for brown colour is correct? what should be it?

Comment: Please include the code you're using...

Answer (score 2):

You can segment a brown object in an image playing around with HSV ranges. Since brown is somehow a *darker* red, you need to tweak the parameters a little. If you post a reference image we could find a more accurate range.

Once you have the object mask (you usually apply some morphology to *clean* the mask), you can easily get the contours with `findContours`.

The example below explains this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    Mat3b img = imread("path_to_image");

    Mat3b hsv;
    cvtColor(img, hsv, COLOR_BGR2HSV);

    Mat1b mask1, mask2;
    inRange(hsv, Scalar(0, 100, 20), Scalar(10, 255, 255), mask1);
    inRange(hsv, Scalar(170, 100, 20), Scalar(180, 255, 255), mask2);

    Mat1b mask = mask1 | mask2;

    Mat1b kernel = getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(7,7));
    morphologyEx(mask, mask, MORPH_OPEN, kernel);

    vector<vector<Point>> contours;
    findContours(mask.clone(), contours, CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

    Mat3b res = img.clone();
    for(int i=0; i<contours.size(); ++i)
    {
        drawContours(res, contours, i, Scalar(0,255,0));

        RotatedRect r = minAreaRect(contours[i]);
        Point2f pts[4];
        r.points(pts);

        for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j)
        {
            line(res, pts[j], pts[(j + 1) % 4], Scalar(0,0,255));
        }

        Rect box = boundingRect(contours[i]);
        rectangle(res, box, Scalar(255,0,0));
    }

    imshow("Original", img);
    imshow("Segmented", res);
    waitKey();

    return 0;
}
```

**Initial image**

[image]

**Segmented brown object (american football)**

[image]

---

**Update with actual image**

Since the image you posted is somehow more difficult then the one in my former example (because you have a lot of *almost brown* color outside the pupil), you need also to:

1. Correct ranges values
2. Find the largest blob

This code show this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    Mat3b img = imread("D:\\SO\\img\\eye.jpg");

    Mat3b hsv;
    cvtColor(img, hsv, COLOR_BGR2HSV);

    Mat1b mask;
    inRange(hsv, Scalar(2, 100, 65), Scalar(12, 170, 100), mask);

    Mat1b kernel = getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(3, 3));
    morphologyEx(mask, mask, MORPH_OPEN, kernel);

    vector<vector<Point>> contours;
    findContours(mask.clone(), contours, CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);

    if (contours.empty()) {return -1;}

    int idx_largest_blob = 0;
    int size_largest_blob = contours[0].size();
    if (contours.size() > 1)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); ++i)
        {
            if (size_largest_blob < contours[i].size())
            {
                size_largest_blob = contours[i].size();
                idx_largest_blob = i;
            }
        }
    }

    Mat3b res = img.clone();

    drawContours(res, contours, idx_largest_blob, Scalar(0, 255, 0));

    RotatedRect r = minAreaRect(contours[idx_largest_blob]);
    Point2f pts[4];
    r.points(pts);

    for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j)
    {
        line(res, pts[j], pts[(j + 1) % 4], Scalar(0, 0, 255));
    }

    Rect box = boundingRect(contours[idx_largest_blob]);
    rectangle(res, box, Scalar(255, 0, 0));

    imshow("Original", img);
    imshow("Segmented", res);
    waitKey();

    return 0;
}
```

Result:

[image]

Note: if you need something more accurate, you should post a new question asking specifically for pupil detection.
I'll drop a few useful links, just in case:

http://answers.opencv.org/question/12034/face-eyes-and-iris-detection/

https://github.com/trishume/eyeLike

https://github.com/laoyang

http://cmp.felk.cvut.cz/~uricamic/flandmark/

http://opencv-code.com/tutorials/pupil-detection-from-an-eye-image/

http://thume.ca/projects/2012/11/04/simple-accurate-eye-center-tracking-in-opencv/

http://opencv-code.com/tutorials/eye-detection-and-tracking/